# execution of request failed https //www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying the below code but it always gave me the same exception...

using Google calender api v3

```
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.GData.Calendar;

Google.GData.Calendar.CalendarService calendarService = new Google.GData.Calendar.CalendarService("App name");
        calendarService.setUserCredentials("username@gmail.com", "password");

        CalendarQuery query = new CalendarQuery();
        query.Uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full");
        CalendarFeed resultFeed = (CalendarFeed)calendarService.Query(query);
        Console.WriteLine("Your calendars:\n");
        foreach (CalendarEntry entry in resultFeed.Entries)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.Title.Text + "\n");
        }
```

help me!

Comment: Google calendar as far as I know doesn't allow client login you need to use Oauth2.  also I recommend the newest client lib.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/

Comment: DalmTo...
thanks for the response i already updated my nuget dll still i am facing the same problem do i need to use Oauth2 or is there any other way for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access Google Calendar you need to be Authenticated with Oauth2, to my knowledge client login is not allowed with Google Calendar API v3.

**Update:** From the Google Calendar API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth)

> About authorization protocols
>
> Your application must use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) to authorize requests. No other
>   authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses
>   Google+ Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you.

The following is a simple example on how to create an authenticated calendar service.   The code was ripped from the [Google Calendar api C# authentication](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-authentication-with-c/) tutorial

```
 string clientId = "";//From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com
 string clientSecret = "";//From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com
 string userName = ""//  A string used to identify a user.
 string[] scopes = new string[] {
    CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, // Manage your calendars
    CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly // View your Calendars
 };

// here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets {
        ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret
    }, scopes, userName, CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Daimto.GoogleCalendar.Auth.Store")).Result;

// Create the service.
    CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Calendar API Sample",
    });
```

Comment: This is what i can't do i need to follow the Google client login
I am trying with Google.GData.Client.dll, Google.GData.Calendar as i hope it is possible with Google client Login may be i am wrong somewhere now i am referring http://www.fryan0911.com/2009/03/c-using-google-data-apis-on-your.html 
but no result found,I am able to do client login inwith GoogleContacts I am sure there must be something for calender too, Please help me in that context... :)

Comment: that tutorial is from Sunday, March 29, 2009 and is no longer valid with the current version of the Google Calendar api.  Google is shutting down all of the client login APIs. You will need to use Oauth2.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation now i will follow Oauth2

Comment: Anytime. The tutorial has a full project on Github if you want something to play with.